# Vectorizing loop of row-plus-matrix operations

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, multidimensional-array, vectorization

I have matrices A (r x k) and B (m x k), and I want to add each row A[:,i] of the first to B in its entirety and return a separate matrix for each row of the first (equivalently, a 3d matrix of dimension r x m x k). I.e.:

```
import numpy as np

v = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
w = np.zeros((5,2))

def mysum(a,b):
    return np.array([a[i]+b for i in range(a.shape[0])])

mysum(v,w)
```

This returns the desired output, albeit slowly:

```
[array([[1., 2.],
        [1., 2.],
        [1., 2.],
        [1., 2.],
        [1., 2.]]),
 array([[3., 4.],
        [3., 4.],
        [3., 4.],
        [3., 4.],
        [3., 4.]])]
```

I tried using the `axes` argument in `np.add`, but it didn't accept the keyword.

Is there a vectorized way to do this? I cannot figure out how to do it without a slow `for`-loop. I read elsewhere on Overflow that `apply_along_axis` is merely a `for`-loop in disguise, and my timing tests show that the following only runs in slightly less than half the time compared to the above list-comprehension solution, and my experience with vectorization leads me to believe much faster speeds are possible:

```
def notsofastsum(t,x):
    return np.apply_along_axis(np.add,1,t,x)
```

And I don't think using `vectorize` will work, since I found this in [the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

> The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.

Comment: `apply_along_axis` should have the same sort of performance disclaimer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arrays are:

```
In [193]: v.shape, w.shape
Out[193]: ((2, 2), (5, 2))
```

and the result shape: (2, 5, 2)

We can use `broadcasting` to do this:

```
In [195]: v[:,None,:]+w           # (2,1,2) + (5,2)
Out[195]: 
array([[[1., 2.],
        [1., 2.],
        [1., 2.],
        [1., 2.],
        [1., 2.]],

       [[3., 4.],
        [3., 4.],
        [3., 4.],
        [3., 4.],
        [3., 4.]]])
```

Your loop also use `broadcasting`.

```
In [196]: v[0].shape
Out[196]: (2,)
```

It's adding a (2,) shape to a (5,2) - which by `broadcasting` is (1,2) added to (5,2) => (5,2).  And you do this on a loop on the first dimension of `v`.